# systemd start Service B only after Service A has finished

Tags: files, systemd, services, dependencies, systemd-unit

I've been searching around for an hour or two but cannot seem to find the correct solution. Here's the situation:

I have multiple services. I start up Service A, which runs a docker container. That application starts up and then writes a file `isActive` to a mounted directory in the file-system.

I have a Service and Path unit file B. watch.path waits until the `isActive` exists, which runs watch.service and that service file just echo's out "`isActive` exists!".

This portion of the logic works fine. I use `sudo journalctl -xefb` and I watch Service A start up, finish it's registration and then write a file. I then can see that the Service B unit files start, echo out, and finish.

I then have multiple other service files (Service C/D/E/F) that `Require` and `After` the Service B watching service. However, Services C/D/E/F are starting way before Service B starts/finishes.

Here is my current 'watching` service:

```
# watch_for_client.path
[Unit]
Wants=A.service
After=A.service

[Path]
PathExists=/A/B/C/d.txt

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

# watch_for_client.service
[Unit]
After=A.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/echo "file found"
```

And then in the other files, I have

```
[Unit]
Requires=wait_for_client.service
After=wait_for_client.service

[Service]
...
Type=simple
...

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change three things in the service unit file configuration for Services C/D/E/F:

1. in [Unit] section: erase the line with `Requires=wait_for_client.service`
2. in [Unit] section: incorrect name in `After=wait_for_client.service`
    it should be `After=watch_for_client.service` to match service B name
3. in {Install] section: should be `WantedBy=watch_for_client.service`